VMWare geode - Unable to create lucene index for a region via cache.xml
I am trying to create lucene index on one of the columns of a region in cache.xml. However, after loading the xml, I can't see the lucene index.
Here is the Xml:
<cache
    xmlns="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:lucene="http://geode.apache.org/schema/lucene"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache
        http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache/cache-1.0.xsd
        http://geode.apache.org/schema/lucene
        http://geode.apache.org/schema/lucene/lucene-1.0.xsd"
    version="1.0"
    is-server="true">
<region-attributes id="EMPTYATTR" data-policy="empty" scope="distributed-no-ack">
  <subscription-attributes interest-policy="all"/>
</region-attributes>
<region-attributes id="PARTITIONEDATTR" data-policy="partition" enable-subscription-conflation="true">
  <partition-attributes recovery-delay="0" redundant-copies="1" startup-recovery-delay="0/>
</region-attributes>
<region name="AllRegions" refid="EMPTYATTR">
 <region name="Customer" refid="PARTITIONEDATTR">
  <lucene:index name="nameIndex">
    <lucene:field name="firstName"/>
  </lucene:index>
 </region>
</region>
</cache>

After I restart the server and check the lucene indexes via gfsh, it couldn't find any lucene index:
gfsh>list lucene indexes
No Lucene indexes found

Banging my head on this for last few days. What am I doing wrong here?

In the partition-attributes tag, is it redundant-copied="1", shouldn't it be redundant-copies="1"?
Is firstName a field within the objects stored in the Customer region?

@VonC Thanks for pointing that out. But unfortunately, it was a typo. As I can't copy paste the xml from my working laptop to PC, so I had to type it. I have fixed the type in post . And the problem is still there . And yes, firstName is a field within Customer object.

OK. I have left below a few setup topics to check out.

@VonC Did you delete your answer here? I can't see it.

I did not, and I apologized here.
